# How to fix "Hyperloop.defineClass must return a class definition into a variable" exception in Titanium?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I'm trying to do the simplest thing in Appcelerator Hyperloop to define/create my own class, but it's causing my builds to fail (can't build for the simulator or a device) with a build-time error from the console.

I just started with a new blank Alloy project and added a single line to the top of index.js to test it:

```
var MyFooClass = Hyperloop.defineClass('MyFooClass', 'NSObject');
```

The syntax I'm using is what I've seen all over the place in the Appcelerator docs and even their own example app: https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/blob/master/app/lib/ios/subclasses/locationmanagerdelegate.js

The error I get from the console/terminal is:

```
An uncaught exception was thrown!
Hyperloop.defineClass must return a class definition into a variable
```

My environment:

```
Mac OSX 10.11.6
Titanium SDK 6.0.1.GA
Alloy 1.9.5
Hyperloop 2.0.0
Appcelerator Studio 4.8.1.201612050850
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this issue before, but it seems like it's fixed in more recent versions of Hyperloop (3.0.2 at this point). You can report any issues on the [Appcelerator Bug Tracker](http://jira.appcelerator.org) to have them validated, I hope that helps!